# how come Editor\Modified_x0020_By not getting updated with SPO?

Tags: 2013, csom, modified, editor

I am trying to update a files Editor\Modified_0020_By info, but on 2nd execution, I get mixed results. Some files get updates, others don't.

The code looks like this,

```
const string sharePointUserIdSeparator = ";#";
User user = null;
if (metadata.ContainsKey("Editor"))
{
    var currentEditor = metadata["Editor"];
    if (currentEditor.Contains(sharePointUserIdSeparator))
    {
        currentEditor = currentEditor.Substring(currentEditor.IndexOf(sharePointUserIdSeparator, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + sharePointUserIdSeparator.Length);
    }

    user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(currentEditor);
    clientContext.Load(user);
}

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (user != null)
{
    metadata["Editor"] = user.Id + sharePointUserIdSeparator + user.LoginName;
    metadata["Modified_x0020_By"] = metadata["Editor"];
}

foreach (var key in metadata.Keys)
{
    item[key] = metadata[key];
}

//udpate the SP records
item.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The first part is for finding if the information already came from SP. I get errors if I try to put back exactly what I get out of SP into the editor and modified_0020_by fields.

The first time I run these, everything is cool, I can even see the Modified By in SharePointOnline web page. But it seems like the second time I run the code, I'm getting the current executing user as the modifier. I've been at this for a few days now and ready to explode. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think I have something to add. I wrote a small test app, and no matter what I tried, I just COULD NOT update the modified_x0020_by field. So I gave up. I changed everything over to just reading\setting the Editor field. The problem there was getting the Editor in such a way that it could be turned around and simply reset. The secret here is to cast to FieldUserValue THEN get the LookupId and set Editor to THAT lookupid. Then do the update and execute and you're good to go. This worked for me, try it out for you if you're in the predicament.